# Single responsibility principle and building a tree of objects

Tags: class, oop, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

Let a class `Rel` denotes a kind of SQL relationship between two tables (that is `Rel` may be `HasA` or `HasMany`, etc.)

Will it contradict [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) ("class or module should have one, and only one, reason to change") if instance objects of this class will be also nodes of a tree of relations of SQL tables? A node would include table name, list of fields for a `SELECT` query, etc.

I think, it will, because both modifying tree structure (say adding possibility to add `ORDER BY` to subqueries in the tree) and modifying the relation (say allowing/disallowing NULL relations) are reasons of change.

Then if it is a violation of single responsibility principle, I assume that relations should have class methods only and the nodes of the tree (each node having a table and a list of fields to retrieve from SQL) should be mere parameters of the methods, not objects or classes on its own. Right?

However, with nodes of the tree being instances of relationships classes, the syntax is short:

`$Node->unfoldWHERE()` (to return the `WHERE` part of an SQL query build from the root node `$Node` of our tree)

If $Nodes are no more objects of this class, this function call could become longer:

`$Node->{CLASS}->unfoldWHERE($Node)` (here the field `CLASS` is a reference to a relationship class, or in languages not supporting passing a class, an object of this class)

Is there any way both not to break basic OOP principles and make this code short and easy to understand?

Comment: Hm, moreover it seems to remain breaking SRP even after passing $Node as a parameter not the object of the `unfoldWHERE` call, because `unfoldWHERE` isn't strictly dependent on relationship only but also on particular structure of the tree. So I see **no way** to write my code without breaking SRP :-(

Comment: Hm, both my variants violated SRP. But I feel that the second variant of the code does not violate some principle violated by the first one. Which principle it may be?